# A single question for GTA-Online cross-platform?

Tags: discussion

[gta-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-5) and the online component [gta-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-online) are now on 5 separate systems; XBox-360, PS3, XBox-One, PS4, and PC. There are, understandably, questions revolving around whether or not there is any cross-platform multiplayer between any of them. So far we have:

- [GTA V PS4 with PC multiplayer compatibility](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/217451)
- [GTA-V, Online PS3 and PS4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/201733)
- [Can I play GTA 5 with my friend if I have a xbox one and he has a PS 4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244497)
- [Does GTA V Online Network Merge Xbox 360 and PS3 players?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/132838)
- [Can GTA V Online work between Xbox 360 and Xbox One](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/192468)
- [If my friend has GTA 5 for 360 and I have one can I invite them to my game online?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/201057)

Of the ten possible combinations we already have at least five (and a few duplicates of those five). This is not inherently bad, but the answer in *every single* case is the same: There is no cross-platform play between *any* of the systems for this game.

Should we, instead, have single question that asks if there is cross-platform play between any of the five systems the game is on, and close the existing questions as dupes of it?

Answer (score 8):

Having one question we can point to as canonical for all combinations so we can point all of these to it strikes me as a good idea (extra so if the answer is universally no, as it minimizes having questions for all combinations). I say go for it.

Comment: Yeah, I probably won't move on this until some time tomorrow. Give the community more of a chance to vote on this and express any disagreement before I self-answer a question and start close-as-duplicate votes.

Comment: @TrentHawkins - You should add an answer here with a link to the question/answer you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree but would be wary of the Xbox 360 vs. Xbox One combination.  Xbox One is in the process of adding support for Xbox 360 games via backward compatibility functionality.  In a nutshell, you may (in the future, if not now) be able to play GTA V on an Xbox One against someone on an Xbox 360 if you use the 360 disc/games on demand version.

A general "Can I play GTA V against players on another platform?" question will probably have 2 answers, I guess (assuming the example I explained above is the only way to play cross-platform).

**More Info**

It appears from the comments and downvotes people may not understand the Xbox One backward compatibility feature.

http://www.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-one/backward-compatibility

> Play multiplayer with your friends no matter which Xbox console they’re on.

If you play a 360 game on the Xbox One, it will emulate the 360.  This includes multiplayer.  This means you can play multiplayer cross-platform via emulation.

GTA V has not been added so far, but they are adding games to the supported list.  See the link for currently supported games.  This feature was only enabled this month.

Therefore, like I said originally, you should be aware that combining all questions into one may need to cater for this Xbox One feature.  At some point it is viable that the question will have 2 answers.

Comment: Thats a big if. I would disagree that it would ever happen, as even when you play on one, your accessing sifferant servers. I dont think we shoukd cover potential future scenarios, on the basis that realistically, lots could happen in the future.

Comment: No, backward compatibility means you are playing xbox 360 through the xbox one.  They have it for some games already.

Comment: Your using the console, but it still uses the original 360 servers to play online. This was even confirmed by Microsoft. Might be worth the technicality that you could buy the 360 version and play it on the xbox ones 360 emulator, but thats about it.

Comment: You will almost certainly not be able to play GTA V (360) with GTA V (XBone), regardless of the actual platform used. That would be an absurd amount of work for Rockstar to do for no gain.

Comment: @Dallium - I never said GTA V (360) with GTA V (XBone).  I said GTA V (360) on a 360 with GTA V (360) on a XBone.

Comment: Oh. Thats not cross platform

Comment: @Dallium - You see now why I said to be aware.  The OP wants to consolidate multiple questions, but there is a snag with regards to Xbox One vs. Xbox 360 that is worth mentioning.  The consolidation should cater for this (well, this is my opinion and the basis of my suggested answer).  It covers things like "Can I play against 360 players" and confusion over whether backward compatibility supports GTA V (note - currently not but this is subject to change, and that is not speculation if you see the official links...i.e. there will be more games added).